# How to get content from MS word cells with VBA and clean it for Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get content from cells of a MS word document and copy it into an excel document with a macro using VBA.

I am using this function in order to achieve it:

```
Cells(insertRow, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
```

But this only brings the text with spaces, without respecting the line jumps (carriage returns).

I have also tried to use both of this:

```
Cells(insertRow, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range)
```

And

```
Cells(insertRow, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol))
```

With the same result.

That would be the main task. I would also like to know if it is possible to change this [symbol from MS word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7N2yO.png) into something similar in excel.

Comment: Ok, i just realised that WorksheetFunction.Clean makes dissapear the first 32 Ascii nonprinting characters. I have to use it to clean some unwanted characters, but this also makes me lose line jump character (which i first have to 'translate' from word to excel using str = Replace(.Cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text, Chr(13), vbCrLf)). Will have to figure out how to clean all except vbCrLf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a long while to figure out how to do this, as it was my first time programming in Visual Basic and VBA, but this is how i solved it:

The first problem i had was that i had some junk characters i had to get rid of, which i tried using

```
WorksheetFunction.Clean(MyString)
```

Problem is this deletes non printing characters which are imported (ASCII code 0-31) which included ascii code 13 (line jump or carriage return).

Even without using WorksheetFunction.clean line jump was not correctly interpreted by excel, which i solved using this

```
Dim str as String
Dim clearer As String
str=.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text 'Get non treated content from word table cell
clearer = Replace(str, Chr(13), vbNewLine)
```

Now that i was not cleaning  automatically all stuff, i had to do it manually, but i did not know the Ascii code of strange characters.

I looked for them this way

```
 Dim Counter As Integer
MsgBox ("Word " + str)
For Counter = 1 To Len(str)
MsgBox ("Letter is " + Mid(str, Counter, 1) + "And Ascii code is" + 
 CStr(AscW(Mid(str, Counter, 1))))
Next
```

Once I knew their code, the process for manual cleaning was the same for other characters. Some of them represented a line_jump and some others were junk, so i treated them in a different way

```
clearer = Replace(str, Chr(13), vbNewLine) 'Replace line jumps from word to excel
clearer = Replace(clearer, Chr(11), vbNewLine) 'Replace line jumps from word 
to excel
clearer = Replace(clearer, Chr(7), "") 'Remover char
```

This way, i could clean the imported text as i wanted. Hope this can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a symbol at the end of each line in the MS word file so as to recover the line jumps. For exemple, if you finish your lines by a semicolon, you could ask Excel to look for the semicolon, and when it finds it, skip a line.

To remove the spaces you could consider runing this code :

```
newString = Replace(strString, " ", "")
```

There may be other ways to achieve what you wish to do, but this feels like the simplest way. 
Hope this helped!

Comment: I am not looking to skip spaces, i just wanted to explain that spaces are accepted and line jumps are not, for some reason. Also, the word document is too wide to start inserting characters after each line and then replace them with a line skip. I appreciate the answer, anyway!